# Asymptotic Distribution of beta distribution parameter

Tags: r, distributions, estimation, data-transformation, gamma-distribution

I am trying to create a t-interval for the first shape parameter of a Beta distributed variable based on a random sample.

$ f(x;\theta,\beta) = \dfrac{\Gamma(\theta+\beta)}{\Gamma(\theta)\Gamma(\beta)}x^{\theta-1}(x-1)^{\beta-1}$

Given that

$E[X]=\dfrac{\theta}{\theta+\beta}$, I found

$MME(\theta) = \dfrac{\beta\overline{X}}{1-\overline{X}}$

So I want to calculate a $(1-\alpha)*100\%$ t confidence interval by using

$\dfrac{\beta\overline{X}}{1-\overline{X}} \pm t_{\alpha/2,n-1}*SE\left[\dfrac{\beta\overline{X}}{1-\overline{X}}\right]$

For the sake of my estimation, I will be fixing $\beta=4$. I have tried and tried to get this in generality as I feel like at it's heart all this quanity represents is a transformation of the sample mean (Delta method/CLT) but I can not for the life of me get any traction on it.

After trying and failing, I ran some simulations and in a couple examples, setting

$\theta=2$ , $\beta=4$, the ratio of

$\dfrac{Var\left[\dfrac{\beta\overline{X}}{1-\overline{X}}\right]}{Var(\overline{X})} \approx 81.7$

Setting $\theta=3$ , $\beta=4$, ratio $\approx 151.5$

Those don't help too much, but do give me estimates to test against once I come to a theoretical result. If anybody can shed some light on my shortcomings I would appreciate it. Either way, thank you taking the time to look.

R code I wrote for testing ratios of variances.

```
test <- function(alpha=1,beta=1){
ratio <- numeric()
for (j in 1:100){
  means <- numeric()
  alphas <- numeric()  
  for (i in 1:1000){    
    sample <- rbeta(100,alpha,beta)
    means[i] <- mean(sample)
    alphas[i] <- beta*mean(sample)/(1-mean(sample))    
  }  
  ratio[j] <- var(alphas)/var(means)  
}
paste0("Ratio of Var: ",round(mean(ratio),3),". Ratio of SD: ",round(sqrt(mean(ratio)),3))
}

mapply(test,alpha=1:5,beta=4,SIMPLIFY=F)
```

Comment: Why use a t-interval for this problem? Where does the t-distribution arise?

Comment: I suppose it was the only thing that came to mind. If I want to create a confidence interval for the parameter based solely on a sample of say size 30, given the MME is a function of the sample mean which has a t-distribution (technically I don't know the variance), I figured that was the route to take. I could be way off base though.

Comment: The sample mean doesn't have a t-distribution just because you don't know the variance. You've got several ideas jumbled up there.